# How to regex_replace on reference

Tags: c++, reference

I have this method:

```
std::string pluralize(std::string const& word) const {
        std::regex_replace(word, m_pattern, m_replacement);
        return word;
    }
```

But it not working as expected. String is not replaced by given rule. Is possible to do `regex_replace` on reference and than return this reference of variable?

Comment: Unfortunately "not working as expected" is a pretty bad problem description. What happens? What should happen? Can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us, including how you call this function? Also please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "it not working as expected" - well, 1) how *is* it working? 2) what did you expect? How do you expect us to guess the difference between what you have and what you expect when you tell us neither..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex_replace` doesn't change in place, but returns the new `string`:

```
std::string pluralize(std::string const& word) const {
    return std::regex_replace(word, m_pattern, m_replacement);;
}
```

If you want to edit the original `string`:

```
void pluralize(std::string &word) const {
    word = std::regex_replace(word, m_pattern, m_replacement);
}
```

And if you want both modify and return:

```
std::string pluralize(std::string &word) const {
    return word = std::regex_replace(word, m_pattern, m_replacement);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to rewrite original string on original address

Comment: @Baterka You can't take a `const` string if you want to modify it.